# Getting rid of some special symbol while reading from a file

Tags: bash

I am writing a small script which is getting some configuration options from a settings file with a certain format (option=value or option=value1 value2 ...).

settings-file:

```
SomeOption=asdf
IFS=HDMI1 HDMI2 VGA1 DP1
SomeOtherOption=ghjk
```

Script:

```
for VALUE in $(cat settings | grep IFS | sed 's/.*=\(.*\)/\1/'); do
    echo "$VALUE"x
done
```

Now I get the following output:

```
HDMI1x
HDMI2x
VGA1x
xP1
```

Expected output:

```
HDMI1x
HDMI2x
VGA1x
DP1x
```

I obviously can't use the data like this since the last read entry is mangled up somehow. What is going on and how do I stop this from happening?

Regards

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: whats the special character? Can you `cat -v` the file?

Comment: `cat -v` shows a `^M` symbol after each line.

Comment: Yet another CRLF issue :D Anyway... run `dos2unix settings` & you are good to go. If `dos2unix` is not available, use `sed -i 's/\r$//' settings`

Comment: That's DOS line endings. Run `dos2unix` command on the file. If you do not have "dos2unix", or run `tr -d '^M' < input_file` - make sure you enter ^M by keystrokes `Ctrl+v+m`

Comment: The colleagues are using Windows and they want to edit the file as well, so I guess I'll go with the additional `sed` command as it's the easiest and most obvious method while keeping the file as it is.

Comment: `tr -cd "[:print:]\n" < file` should remove all non-printable characters from the file. Also btw your script demonstrates perfect UUOC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat :)

Comment: @Inian That will remove tabs also.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can use `awk` like this:

```
awk -F'[= ]' '$1=="IFS"{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $i"x"}' settings
```

`-F'[= ]` splits the line by `=` or space. The following awk program checks if the first field, the variable name equals `IFS` and then iterates trough column 2 to the end and prints them.

However, in comments you said that the file is using Windows line endings. In this case you need to pre-process the file before using awk. You can use `tr` to remove the carriage return symbols:

```
tr -d '\r' settings | awk -F'[= ]' '$1=="IFS"{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $i"x"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is likely that your settings file uses DOS line endings.

Once you've fixed that (with `dos2unix` for example), your loop can also be modified to the following, removing two utility invocations:

```
for value in $( sed -n -e 's/^IFS.*=\(.*\)/\1/p' settings ); do
  echo "$value"x
done
```

Or you can do it all in one go, removing the need to modify the settings file at all:

```
tr -d '\r' <settings |
for value in $( sed -n -e 's/^IFS.*=\(.*\)/\1/p' ); do
  echo "$value"x
done
```